# HTML (or Rails) button code issue

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, button

I'm struggling with the following problem: What's the correct HTML (and/or Rails) code for

- a button that resides within a form, and
- that should lead to a new page, but
- should *not* submit anything (from the form)?

Basically, the button should work exactly like a hyperlink.

Thanks for your help!

Tom

Comment: It has to be a button simply for design reasons (consistency)...

Comment: Couldn't you just stylize it as a button with css?

Comment: @Trip: I can't style the buttons in this case, I have to use the raw browser format. And as far as I know, it's not possible to turn a hyperlink into a button, using CSS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try the "button_to" tag: [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work: Usually, Rails would embed a submit button within an additional form. In my case, the button is already within a form, which apparently makes Rails drop the second additional form (probably because a form within a form is invalid HTML). Therefor, I'd end up with a submit button within a form, which POSTs the form - which should *not* happen...

Comment: Good point, I should've anticipated that.  Well, there are a couple hacks.  You could have a button image within a link (link_to image_tag ...), or you could use html/javascript for input type=button and have the onclick redirect you to a different page.

Comment: Thanks - the javascript proposal is the best, given my conditions. In Rails speak, the code then become: button_to_function 'Go to new page' do |page| page.redirect_to whatever_path end

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but for teh Googlez I have a non-JS solution. You can extract the button to a helper method, and then return the html for the button with the link generated by url_for. Use a dummy button as a link and you won't have to worry about doing something fancy to style the button.

```
def back_button
  target_url = url_for :controller => :users, :action => :new
  "<a href=#{target_url} style='text-decoration:none;'><button type='button'>&lt;&lt; Back</button></a>"
end
```